# List view item on click send to another page

Tags: c#, list, xaml, view, windows-phone

I have something like this:

[image]

XAML (for one item):

```
  <ListView Margin="10,0,10,10" Width="360" Height="510" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.479,0.497">
            <ListViewItem RenderTransformOrigin="0.719,0.534">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Assets/1.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Width="302" RenderTransformOrigin="0.698,0.49" SelectionChanged="TextBlock_SelectionChanged" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False">
                        <Run Text="Stotis–Oro uostas"/>
                    </TextBlock>
```

C#:

```
private void TextBlock_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
    }
```

I want to make like that: When I click on 1st item it should send me to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add tapped listener to the listview items like this:

```
 <ListView Margin="10,0,10,10" Width="360" Height="510" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.479,0.497">
        <ListViewItem x:Name="ListViewItem1" Tapped="ListViewItem1_Tapped">
            <!--add your image and text and ...-->
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem x:Name="ListViewItem2" Tapped="ListViewItem2_Tapped">
            ...
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem x:Name="ListViewItem3" Tapped="ListViewItem3_Tapped">
            ...
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

Than you can add in the code behind file this:

```
private void ListViewItem1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FirstPage));
    }

    private void ListViewItem2_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
    }

    private void ListViewItem3_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ThirdPage));
    }
```

I hope this is like you wanted it.